# Are [xml-entities], [html-entities], and [character-entities] actually one entity?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request, synonym-request

There are three very similar tags:

- [html-entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html-entities), with 1335 questions
- [xml-entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xml-entities), with 54 questions
- [character-entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/character-entities), with 45 questions

These all seem to describe the same thing: the method of typing characters using an ampersand and a semicolon (e.g., `&nbsp;`) described on the [tag wiki for html-entities](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/html-entities/info).

Proposal: these tags should be merged, with synonyms created, into one [character-entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/character-entities) tag with the current wiki for [html-entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html-entities).

Comment: Not an SME– is "character-entities" too generic? Or is that a formal name for what "html entities" intends to refer to? Just want to make sure the final tag name is still recognizable to folks.

Comment: @zcoop98 my thought was that creating synonyms would go a long way toward helping with that, so that at least typing "html-entities" would get you the right tag.  Also not an SME, though.

Comment: @zcoop98 they would formally be called "SGML character entity references" and most people not familiar with XML would probably call them "HTML entities" but to people who work with XML this would definitely rub the wrong way!

Comment: Also there's an [tag:entityreference] tag that seems to be a mix of some kind of Drupal object and others that are referencing (HT|X)ML entities and should be retagged.

Comment: What are character-entities?

Comment: @Dharman a generic term to cover both (a shorter version of "SGML character entity references") ...but better naming ideas are very welcome.

Comment: These tags may also need merging and/or clarification: [tag:character-reference], [tag:html-escape-characters], [tag:entity], [tag:entities]

Answer (score 3):

[html-entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html-entities) and [xml-entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xml-entities) are certainly different.

- XML has `&quot;` `&amp;` `&apos;` `&lt;` and `&gt;` and that's all.
- HTML has all that XML has and more e.g. `&nbsp;`

You can [read more about html and xml entities in wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references).

I expect character entites is the generic term where you're encoding something, could be HTML, could be XML, could be something else I suppose. Other data formats such as JSON have completely different [character entities](https://www.mastertemplate.co.uk/jsonescapedcharacterentities.php).

So in short I don't think you can or should combine these.

The tag wiki for [xml-entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xml-entities) is very strange though and doesn't seem to match the questions it's being used for.

Comment: Thanks, I actually didn't know this (which is exactly the sort of feedback I was hoping to get).  That said, we have tags that cover the same general idea as implemented differently in different languages/frameworks.  Is it not close enough to be covered by the same tag, especially if one is a superset of the other?

Comment: One's a subset of the other, I don't think that makes them very different at all, nor does it mean they shouldn't be merged.

Comment: If one tags a question as xml-entities and then asks why &nbsp; isn't working then we have something to go on. If that's changed to html-entities then the question would make a lot less sense.

Comment: IMO the only reason not to merge/synonymize these tags is if there's a non-SGML context where "character entity" means something. I think the combination of "xml" and "charater-entities" would make things clear

Comment: @miken32 like [json character entities?](https://www.mastertemplate.co.uk/jsonescapedcharacterentities.php) for instance?

Comment: I think those are properly called escape sequences.

Comment: When would I use either of those tags instead of simply using html or xml for my markdown?

Comment: @Braiam — presumably, when you have a question about XML entities, you'd use the [tag:xml-entities] to further qualify what aspect of XML is under discussion.  Etc.

Comment: lol no `<!ENTITY>`

Comment: @JonathanLeffler and in what way that helps my question to be answered that [xml] doesn't and doesn't require me to know that entities exist? Also, isn't that what my title is for? "How to represent dashes as data on my xml file?" If I know about entities, I wouldn't use the xml-entities tags at all, since if I know about them I wouldn't ask the question. So, again: when should I use it if everything I know is that I have a problem with xml?

Answer (score -5):

You are looking at the wrong tags to merge into. XML entities are not relevant outside XML. HTML entities are not relevant outside of HTML. Character entities is totally ambiguous and should not exist. So, merge X-entities into their X.